# backup one table per day in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, backup, synchronization

I want to log test data into a postgresql database. This will be a new table each day, name then something like testtable_16122017.
At the end of each day this table will be backed up to another SQL server. So I dont need synchronisation and all that, since the table will be created once, filled with data and never changed again.
Can this be done with Slony, or maybe I just have to put a few lines in the testrig software, that at the end of each day this table will be pushed into backup database?
Why all that, there is a Labview PC at the testrig and an SQL server in a LAN So if anything else breaks down, we still get the test data. And for furhter analysis and backup it will be sent to another server later on. Also I have to worry less about performance.

Thanks!

Comment: https://pgxn.org/dist/tds_fdw/

Comment: got told I can set up a Windows task. I guess I can do something like pgdump on shutdown. On shutdown because I know thats the end of the day, the table should not get more values. Both servers will have postgres I hope, still have to convice the admin